# Change an action bar color in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

this question is already ask on stack overflow but didn't work for me.

I want to change my action bar color only like facebook app the top action is in blue color and rest of the thing has white background color.

I tried using the post in stack overflow but, it's change my full activity color to white instead of just only the action bar.

Here is my style.xml and

```
<style name="CustomActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@color/blue_base</item>
    <!-- other activity and action bar styles here -->
</style>
```

manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/CustomActivityTheme">
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your target API level?

Comment: It's 17 . android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="17"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a color directly, you have to use a drawable :

**action_bar_bg.xml** :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/blue_base"/>
</shape>
```

Then this should work :

```
<item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I realized where you did wrong. You can't pass color to `actionBarTabStyle`, you have to pass style. Instead you can define your `style` and pass it to it like this,

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
</style>
```

This example from [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style) page, if you take a look at there they explain very well.

There is another good article also on [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html)